# keep the columns with head contains a string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this

```
ID rs_2312 ._C ._G rs_8923 ._A ._T
2  2       1    1  5       2   4
3  3       6    6  7       8   9
```

My desired ouput is

```
rs_2312 rs_8923 
2       5       
3       7
```

That is I want to keep the columns with name contains "rs". In the real file, the number of columns is very large. I cannot to count it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^rs/) h[i]} 
            {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                printf "%s", ((i in h)?$i FS:""); print ""}' file | 
  column -t

rs_2312  rs_8923
2        5
3        7
```

Comment: this checks whether column name starts with "rs", if you want contains check remove the `^` circumflex sign

Comment: I have a new problem. Some columns is like "rs8923_AGGG", "rs8923241233_A", and "rs564523241233_GKEE". But I only want to the columns like this "rs8923241233_A", that is there is only one character after underscore.I tried change `/^rs/` as `/^rs*_?/` but it does not work.

Comment: I also tried `/^rs[:digit:]_[...]$/` .But it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it very simply with formatted output via `printf`, e.g.

```
$ awk '{printf "%-8s %s\n", $2, $5}' file.txt
rs_2312  rs_8923
2        5
3        7
```

`printf` gives you the range of format control you would have in C (or bash or awk). It is another way to maintain the format you seek. See `man 3 printf` for the complete *format string* and *format specifier* options..

In addition to `awk`, you can use a simple `while` loop as well, e.g.:

```
$ while read -r t r12 t t r23 t; do \
    printf "%-8s %s\n" "$r12" "$r23" \
done <file.txt
```

Which will produce the same output. (*note:* above you only care about the columns `2` & `5` which you assign the variable `r12` and `r23`, for the remainder of fields the same *dummy* or *temp* variable `t` is used.) Also the last `t` will read the remainder of the line regardless of its format after reading `r23`.